# Vertical dodge in geom_jitter

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have an ethogram-like ggplot where I plot the value of a factor `quadrant` (1 to 4), which is plotted for each frame of a movie (`frameID`). The color is given by 3 animals that are being tracked.

I am fairly satisfied with the graph but the amount of points makes it difficult to see, even with `alpha`. I was wondering how to add `position_dodge` in a way that doesn't destroy the plot.

```
ggplot(dataframe) ,
         aes(frameID, quadrant, color=animal)) +
    geom_jitter(alpha=0.5) +
    scale_color_manual(values =  c("#1334C1","#84F619", "#F43900")) + 
    theme_classic()+ 
    theme(legend.position = 'none')
```

[image]

This link has useful info about dodging using `geom_point`.
[R: How to spread (jitter) points with respect to the x axis?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31405985/r-how-to-spread-jitter-points-with-respect-to-the-x-axis)

I can change to `geom_point` with height, which works but it produces something awful.

`+ geom_point(position = position_jitter(w = 0, h = 2))`

[image]

## Update

Data lives in GitHub

Lowering the alpha or changing size helps, adds trouble when rescaling the image.

https://github.com/matiasandina/MLA2_Tracking/blob/master/demo_data/sample_data.csv

### Update 2022

It's been a while since I posted this initially, my original thoughts changed and are better reflected [here](https://discuss.ropensci.org/t/ggethos-gauging-interest-in-ggplot-extension-to-plot-ethograms-and-potential-collaborators/3078), but I am still looking for a `ggplot2` version of doing this!

Comment: Sharing some of your data would be useful.

Comment: @Julius please see my edit. I posted a small fraction because the data is huge. I was actually thinking about downsampling

Comment: I'm afraid it doesn't really help, all the observations are from the second quadrant and the same animal. Perhaps you could pick a number of random rows.

Comment: @Julius My bad, messed up the subset

Comment: Now the problem is that the sample data isn't enough to reproduce the issue.. Maybe you could upload the data somewhere or simulate it? As for the question itself, have you tried setting `alpha` to something quite lower, like 1 / 20, and adding, e.g., `size = 0.2` to `geom_jitter`?

Comment: As far as I know, a geom can have one `position` argument, and both dodging and jittering are implemented as positions. Easiest work around is probably to manually jitter your data (add a column of `runif(nrow(your_data), -.3, .3)` or something like that) and use the position argument for dodging. Julius's advice to reduce the size and alpha values will also help.